# undefined method `t' for Admin::FaqsController:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-i18n

in my project i have controller in namespace admin and I'm using breadcrumbs_on_rails to build breadcrums. My controller looks like:
module Admin

```
class FaqsController < Admin::ApplicationController
    include FaqsHelper
    load_and_authorize_resource

   add_breadcrumb t('faqs.faqs_list') , :faqs_path #this line makes the problem
    def index
      @faqs = @faqs
      add_breadcrumb t('faqs.faqs_list')

    end

    def new
      add_breadcrumb t('faqs.new')
    end

 #other code ommitted
  end
end
```

i can use t method in new, edit and other controller action but when this 't' is not in the controller action i have the follwoing error:

```
undefined method `t' for Admin::FaqsController:Class
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use `I18n.t` instead of just `t`.

Comment: I was getting the same error when using in custom library file. This solves the problem. Thanx!

Comment: If you feel verbose to call `I18n.t` every time, you can add this line to your `ApplicationController`: `delegate :t, to: I18n`

Comment: Hey but with `I18n.t` or `delegate :t, to: I18n` you cannot make use of lazy_lookout you have to name the whole thing. `t('.home.index.logged_in')` intead of `t(.logged_in)`

Answer (score 4):

I can suggest to extend your class with
`extend ActionView::Helpers::TranslationHelper`
It will allow you to use `#t` and `#l` helpers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [Skydan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1116374/skydan) but `extend` would work only for modules. I made it work by adding `include ActionView::Helpers::TranslationHelper` to my controller.