# How do I access my string in my locales file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-5, locale

I want to access the following string from our config/locales/en.yml file in my coffee script page ..

```
en:
  share_message: "Help our organization."
```

Following this guide -- http://primegap.net/2011/02/28/rails-quicktip-variables-i18n-localized-strings/, I thought the way to do it was to do

```
<%= t("share_message") %>
```

but this results in a

```
undefined method `t' for #<#<Class:0x00007f97ae3ddd88>:0x00007f97a7b37ae0>
```

error.  What's the proper way to access the string in teh locales file?  This is with Ruby on Rails 5.1.

Comment: "in my coffee script page" could you please paste that page? are we talking about a partial?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [undefined method \`t' for Admin::FaqsController:Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878676/undefined-method-t-for-adminfaqscontrollerclass)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explicitly call it with class:

```
<%= I18n.t("share_message") %>
```

You can read more about internationalization [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it in as a symbol

```
<%= t(:share_message)%>
```

remember `t()` is an aliase of `I18n.t()`.